# R Group by date to get frequency and use another column to filter

Tags: r, plyr

I have the following R dataframe.  I would like to get the frequency by date but use the `Min` column to keep the freq 0 if it is 0.  How should I go about this?

Below is my dataframe:

```
library(plyr)

df
  Location   Date            Min six endsix seven seventeen starteighteen eighteen

1 location_1 2018-11-21       0 360    415   420      1020          1025     1080
2 location_1 2018-11-22       0 360    415   420      1020          1025     1080
3 location_1 2018-11-23     131 360    415   420      1020          1025     1080
4 location_1 2018-11-24       0 360    415   420      1020          1025     1080
5 location_1 2018-11-25    1001 360    415   420      1020          1025     1080
6 location_1 2018-11-25     272 360    415   420      1020          1025     1080
7 location_1 2018-11-25    1319 360    415   420      1020          1025     1080
```

If I do the following `count(location_1, "Date")` I get

```
   Date          freq
1  2018-11-21    1
2  2018-11-22    1
3  2018-11-23    1
4  2018-11-24    1
5  2018-11-25    5
```

I would like to do this but if there is a 0 for the `Min` column have 0 for the frequency like the following:

```
   Date          freq
1  2018-11-21    0
2  2018-11-22    0
3  2018-11-23    1
4  2018-11-24    0
5  2018-11-25    5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `data.table`:

```
# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1)

# data frame
df <- data.frame(Date = sample(seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-09"), by = "days"), 30, replace = T), 
           Min = sample(c(0:5), 30, replace = T), stringsAsFactors = F)

# load packages
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

# make df into data.table
setDT(df)

# establish which Date values have Min = 0
minVals <- df[Min == 0, unique(Date)]

# Count date and set those rows with Date Min = 0 to 0
res <- df[, .N, by = 'Date'][
  Date %in% minVals, N := 0
  ]
```

Result:

```
> res
         Date N
1: 2019-01-03 0
2: 2019-01-04 0
3: 2019-01-06 0
4: 2019-01-09 5
5: 2019-01-02 5
6: 2019-01-01 2
7: 2019-01-07 0
8: 2019-01-05 1
9: 2019-01-08 1
```

It woudl be nice if you post a snippet of your data in a way that we can actually test it when trying to provide an answer. Try `dput(head(df, 10))`, `R` will display on the console an output that should be a piece of code that constructs a snippet of your actual data.

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

count(df, Date) %>% 
  mutate(n = ifelse(Date %in% pull(filter(df, Min == 0), Date), 0, n))
```

Resulting in:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  Date           n
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2019-01-01     2
2 2019-01-02     5
3 2019-01-03     0
4 2019-01-04     0
5 2019-01-05     1
6 2019-01-06     0
7 2019-01-07     0
8 2019-01-08     1
9 2019-01-09     5
```

Comment: Great answer's! I used the datatable answer and added `df2 = setDF(res)` @JdeMello

Comment: Great @sectechguy. I understand you are working on the `tidyverse` and I posted a solution that conforms to your request but it is also a good idea to provide a `data.table` solution because `data.table` is very fast for these type of operations.